# Create output files from a string array

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I need to create 4 output files.

I currently obtain a single file.

```
String url1 = "www.xxxx.com";
String url2 = "www.xxxx.com";
String url3 = "www.xxxx.com";
String url4 = "www.xxxx.com";
String tableaurl[] = {url1,url2,url3,url4};

for(String url : tableaurl)
{
      String encodedString = UrlUtils.encodeAnchor(url);
      System.out.format("%s\n", encodedString);
      URL myURL = new URL(encodedString);
      String userpass = "username" + ":" + "password";
      String basicAuth = "Basic " +  Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        URLConnection myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection(proxy);
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        myURLConnection.connect();
        InputStream is = myURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        File dir = new File(home + File.separator + "collected" +  File.separator +"test");
        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir + File.separator + date.getTime()); 
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Comment: This code should already create 4 files marked by `new File(dir + File.separator + date.getTime());` (assuming different times)

Comment: hello cricket_007, thanks you.

Comment: This is the end of the code :String line;
    try {
     
     int read = 0;
     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
     while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
      fos.write(bytes, 0, read);
      // sb.append(line);
     }
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     
    }

Comment: have to create a loop for the end, to obtain 4 files ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.... That comment is reading the inputstream and writing to a single file. `for(String url : tableaurl)` already loops a total of 4 times and should create 4 files, as I said

Comment: OK, thank you very much  it is this comment which masked 4 created files.
I am then going to delete it.

Comment: while creating new file - `new File(dir + File.separator + date.getTime());` you are using the same object `date` which i am guessing is created outside for loop. So, the date.getTime() is returning same output for each url!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 4 files, then use 4 distinct names.

```
int i = 0; // Some number counter
for(String url : tableaurl) {
    // other code...

    i++;   
    File file = new File(dir + File.separator + i + "_" + date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use different date object to create different file name. Currently you are using a single object which returns the same time each time you call get time().

You can use new Date().get time().

Comment: hello Python, with new Date().get time(), not need to use a loop. Thanks